# Prevent non admin users from accessing keychain

Tags: security, password, keychain

Ive setup mail accounts on an employees computer and noticed that they were able to view the passwords by looking in the keychain, what id like to do is not allow them to view the passwords stored in the keychain unless they have the administrators login / password, in a similar way to when they try to install software they get prompted for it.

Is that possible to do ?

Comment: Did you lock the keychain? I'm admin on my own machine & every time I want to view a password I must enter the keychain password.

Comment: @Tetsujin - when you say you have to enter the admin password, im guessing thats when your on your own account, im talking about a sub user (non admin) being able to access the keychain on their account user their password, even though this is their keychain it contains passwords from mail.app that might be used else where ideally id like them to have no access to keychain without an administrators password

Comment: ahh... then I'm not sure, sorry.